REST API call from synapse notebook to any other services outside azure not working ( power bi , Google)
REST API call from synapse notebook to any other services outside azure not working ( power bi , Google)
ex:
test_url = "https://www.google.com"
response = requests.get(test_url)
print("Google Response Code:", response.status_code)

ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7faccbae2650>, 'Connection to www.google.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
We verified the network and firewall are allowed for public internet and not ip restrictions.
is there any config settings i can review on Spark instance ?

Have you tried with another URL's?

I have tried the requests features:
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
url = "https://www.google.com"
session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
try:
    response = session.get(url)
    print(f"Response Code: {response.status_code}")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Request failed: {e}")

Results:
Response Code: 200

In the above code will retrieve a URL and attempt to retry the request up to three times if a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError occurs.
The backoff_factor parameter will introduce delays between each attempt to prevent the request from failing again due to periodic request quota.
You can also check urllib3.util.retry.Retry for other retry options.
